# Something wrong when I install pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I installed pip on `python2.7`. When I typed 'pip' there were some errors. Anyone could tell me why? Thanks a lot!

Here's the error:

```
C:\Users\ckf>pip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==8.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\__init__.py", line 207, in main
        cmd_name, cmd_args = parseopts(args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\__init__.py", line 166, in parseopts
        parser.print_help()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1670, in print_help
        file.write(self.format_help().encode(encoding, "replace"))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1650, in format_help
        result.append(self.format_option_help(formatter))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1633, in format_option_help
        result.append(group.format_help(formatter))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1114, in format_help
        result += OptionContainer.format_help(self, formatter)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1085, in format_help
        result.append(self.format_option_help(formatter))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1074, in format_option_help
        result.append(formatter.format_option(option))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 316, in format_option
        help_text = self.expand_default(option)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\baseparser.py", line 112, in expand_default
        return optparse.IndentedHelpFormatter.expand_default(self, option)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 288, in expand_default
        return option.help.replace(self.default_tag, str(default_value))
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You're not using pip correctly. Correct usage is `pip install [options] ...`. Eg. `pip install numpy`

Comment: it's because of the user name you gave your computer for example `Kévin`gives you that error whereas `Kevin` it's fine

Comment: @Narendra typing simply `pip` is just fine: that should show you the generic help, not crash with an unicode error.

Comment: pip expects something to be ascii which it is not. That is all I can see. It is indeed weird.

Comment: I unistalled it ，then installed it again. Using 'python setup.py install' to install pip,but when I type 'pip',the error exists again. That's really makes mad.

Answer (score -1):

The story started when I wanted to use matplotlib. I installed 'matplotlib-1.4.0.win32-py2.7.exe', then I typed 'from pylab import *',it said I didn't have 'six',so I installed 'six-1.7.3.win32-py2.7.exe' and 'python-dateutil-2.2.win32-py2.7.exe' and 'pyparsing-2.0.2.win32-py2.7.exe' and 'numpy-1.8.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe'. Finally,I typed 'from pylab import *' again,errors occured:'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)'

I asked my friend ,he told me to use pip to install matplotlib, so I installed pip.

That's why I met the errors above.I have a good news,I used matplotlib on ubuntu well and I decided to use ubuntu now.Thanks you guys for helping me.